# How to apply max-width style for Firefox/IE/Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I am using the css style `max-width:236px` which produces exact view for chrome/IE but not in Firefox. In order to produce the same thing for Firefox I need to give `max-width:219px`; in this case IE/chrome is not working. How can I give the two different values in max-width properties for cross browser issue. Your suggestions are valuable. Thank you.

```css
// IE/Chrome is good
textboxwidth {
  max-width: 236px;
}

// FireFox is good
textboxwidth {
  max-width: 219px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `box-sizing:border-box`?

Comment: @Paulie_D If i use box-sizing:border-box it is adjusting the text in firefox but in chrome/IE the width of textbox is also reducing.

Answer (score 2):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your style.

Firefox's default TextBox includes more padding than IE/Chrome. `box-sizing: border-box;` changes the width to *include* padding, as opposed to the standard method of adding the two together to get absolute width.

**EDIT:** [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) posted the same answer in the comments above, just to give additional credit where it's due.